# Writing an Excel Macro with a condition

Tags: microsoft-excel

Just a little question.

I have made a macro like this and I have set it to a button in Excel.

```
Range("SUM!F3") = Range("SUM!F3") + Range("Afternoon!N4")
Range("SUM!E3") = Range("SUM!E3") + Range("Afternoon!E4")
```

How can I make this macro be applied when the button is pressed, only when the value in a specified cell is greater than 0?

Comment: `If Range("Yourcell")>0 then` do your stuff `End If`

Comment: Thanks
Can u write an example sir?
@scott-craner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, VBA has an `If` clause that can check a conditional.

Just replace {CELL} with the cell you want to check against:

```
If Range("{CELL}") > 0 Then
    Range("SUM!F3") = Range("SUM!F3") + Range("Afternoon!N4")
    Range("SUM!E3") = Range("SUM!E3") + Range("Afternoon!E4")
End If
```

Source: [If...Then...Else Statement (Visual Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement)

Comment: Please clarify and add a little more context to this answer to convey what you are suggesting exactly and why it works, etc. You know, consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state and why it is.